# How to move a UITableView cell to another view outside of UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I need to move my `UITableView` cell out of its `tableview` but when I try to move `UITableViewCell` then it always within its `tableview` and I need to *animation* while moving as well.

This is my code:

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        //config for HomeTableView
        [HomeTableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
        [HomeTableView setScrollEnabled:YES];
        [HomeTableView setAllowsSelection:YES];
        [HomeTableView setAllowsSelectionDuringEditing:YES];

    }

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath {
        //i just change data source of my tableview at here

        [self showViewGarbageAnimationMoveCell];//show custom view like garbage
        //i want During when i move my cell if it is within bound of custom view -> it will be smaller scaled and be deleted when i end move on this cell. 
        //Unfortunately i can't move my cell to out of its tableview
    }

-(void)showViewGarbageAnimationMoveCell
    {
        UIView * testView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5.0f, 10.0f, 375.0f, 50.0f)];
        [testView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
        [self.view addSubview:testView];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f
                              delay:0.0f
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse
                         animations:^{
                             [testView setFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f, 10.0f, 375.0f, 50.0f)];
                         }
                         completion:nil];
    }
```

Comment: you need to explain what you want to do in more detail.

Comment: That's a good question. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. What are you trying to do?

Comment: i want to when i begin move my cell one custom view like garbage with animation will be showed on UINavigation and if i want to delete my cell which moving then this cell will be dragged into the custom view and it will be deleted

Answer (score 0):

Register `panGesture` with `UITableViewCell` and then when action method of `panGesture` get called do the processing, something like this.

```
- (void)handelPanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer* )panGesture
{
if (panGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        // save reference of start frame of tableViewCell
    }
    else if (panGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        // Check if panGesture.view is going out of UItablView bounds remove it from tableView add it to other View and set

    }
    else if (panGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        // if location is still in tableView set cell.Frame = back to startFrame
        // if not arrange it to new view
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create snapshot of your `UITableViewCell` by using `snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:` function.

After that you can place snapshot `UIView` in any place and move it whatever you want